# Tarantool remote admin console does not ask password

Tags: tarantool

I need to setup remote admin console on tcp(not unix socket) for tarantool. 
According to documentation it is provided with *console* module. 
And I added this to my tarantool config:

```
console.listen("0.0.0.0:3313")
```

Then I can connect to it via telnet or using *tarantoolctl connect*.
But I'm not pleased that it is not password protected. Yes I've read the [docs](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/book/admin/security/#admin-security).
Is there some possibility to get protected console with password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to administer tarantool remotely, with authentication is by opening a regular binary port like this:

```
box.cfg({listen=3301})
```

And then connecting to it with tarantoolctl:

```
tarantoolctl connect admin:password@127.0.0.1:3301
```

So, connect to the instance through the same host:port you'd use to connect with, say, Python or PHP client.

The console module you refer to isn't meant to be used over TCP. It has support for TCP, but it's essentially plaintext, without any authentication. It is only meant to be used by local user who has root account.